# await reserved word problem at firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

If I use the code as in firebase documentation I get the error await is reserved word

```
try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
  first: "Alan",
  middle: "Mathison",
  last: "Turing",
  born: 1912
});
 console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

If I use it like this I don't get any error but this doesn't work

```
async () => {
try {
   const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "projects", vm.add.slug), {
    first: "Alan",
    middle: "Mathison",
    last: "Turing",
    born: 1912
  })
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
} catch (err) {
    console.log("error deleting data:", err)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me what do I do wrong.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: nothing this function never fires. It should and retun an error or log anything to console i guess

Comment: So it appears that you were using `await` without it being in an async function, but then you created an async function that was never called? If that is correct, just be sure to call the function in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said, in the first example, you're calling await in a function that is not an async one, and in the second try, you've only defined a function that was never called.

My suggestion: Create an async function, and call it where you want, with await.

```
    const submit = async payload => {
      try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "projects", vm.add.slug), payload)
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error deleting data:", err)
      }
    };
    
    ...
    await submit({
        first: "Alan",
        middle: "Mathison",
        last: "Turing",
        born: 1912
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I figured it out and fixed it but your method seem better I will give it a try now

Comment: Ok :). Could you upvote my answer please?